# Doctrine Migration Bundle: Update Error after upgrade to Version 3

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4, doctrine-migrations

There was a recent upgrade to doctrine-migrations version 3, that came as part of a vendor library upgrade, so we are kind of forced to follow now ;)

We configured it like this:

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        "DoctrineMigrations": "src/Migrations"

    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'migration_versions'
            version_column_name: 'version'
            version_column_length: 1024
            executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
            execution_time_column_name: 'execution_time'
```

Never the less, we get the folowing strange migration error.

`bin/console  doctrine:migrations:status` gives this "everything fine" output:

```
+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Configuration                                                                                                        |
+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Storage              | Type                 | Doctrine\Migrations\Metadata\Storage\TableMetadataStorageConfiguration |
|                      | Table Name           | migration_versions                                                     |
|                      | Column Name          | version                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Database             | Driver               | Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver                                   |
|                      | Name                 | dwconnect2                                                             |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Versions             | Previous             | DoctrineMigrations\Version20200522213838                               |
|                      | Current              | DoctrineMigrations\Version20200608142225                               |
|                      | Next                 | Already at latest version                                              |
|                      | Latest               | DoctrineMigrations\Version20200608142225                               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Migrations           | Executed             | 18                                                                     |
|                      | Executed Unavailable | 0                                                                      |
|                      | Available            | 18                                                                     |
|                      | New                  | 0                                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Migration Namespaces | DoctrineMigrations   | src/Migrations                                                         |
+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But if we run `bin/console  doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction` it throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] The version "latest" couldn't be reached, you are at version "DoctrineMigrations\Version20200608142225"
```

Our database is looking good, as we cleared it out and where running all the migrations fresh.

Thx a lot for any help!
Andreas

Comment: Looks like this is a breaking change introduced into 3.0.0: https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/987

Comment: You are not forced to upgrade, just unpack orm with `composer unpack orm` and pin doctrine-migrations version to `^2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So credits to [this reply](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/987#issuecomment-643996650) on the [original github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/987):

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --allow-no-migration --no-interaction
```

This will convert the error into a warning.

Comment: Version  3.0.1 handles this now gracefully ;) - looks like we have been just a bit too cutting edge.